# Python tkinter label widget mouse over

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, mouseevent

My objective is to change the text of label widget when the mouse move over the label.For one label i would do something like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def fun1(event):
    label.config(text="Haha")
def fun2(event):
    label.config(text="Label1")

root=tk.Tk()
label=tk.Label(root,text="Label1")
label.grid(row=1,column=1)
label.bind("<Enter>", fun1)
label.bind("<Leave>", fun2)
root.mainloop()
```

But now, i have a bunch of labels which is generated by for loop and a list which contains the text that i want to change.

```
mylist=['a','b','c','d','e']
for i in range(5):
    tk.Label(root,text="Label"+str(i)).grid(row=i+1,column=1)
```

This will generate 5 labels with numbers. Is it possible to add mouse over event for each individual label so that when i mouse over on the label 1, it changes to 'a', when i mouse over to label 2, it changes to 'b', etc? FYI, the number of items in the mylist will always be the same with the number used in for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
mylist = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Label "+str(i))
    label.grid(row=i+1, column=1)
    label.bind("<Enter>", lambda e, x=x: e.widget.config(text=x))
    label.bind("<Leave>", lambda e, i=i: e.widget.config(text="Label "+str(i)))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @ChrisAung It uses the actual `x` of the iteration for the lambda function. Otherwise, it will show "e" for all the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Event functions can be included in a class and strings for displaying can be defined by a constructor.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Labels(object):
    def __init__(self,number,basicStr,onMouseStr):
        self.i = number
        self.basicStr = basicStr + str(number)
        self.onMouseStr = onMouseStr
        mylist=['a','b','c','d','e']
        self.label = tk.Label(root,text="Label"+str(i))
        self.label.grid(row=1+i,column=1)
        self.label.bind("<Enter>", self.fun1)
        self.label.bind("<Leave>", self.fun2)
    def fun1(self,event):
        self.label.config(text=self.basicStr)
    def fun2(self,event):
        self.label.config(text=self.onMouseStr)
root=tk.Tk()
labelsList = []
for i in range(5):
    lab = Labels(i,"haha","label"+str(i))
    labelsList.append(lab)
root.mainloop()
```